# Angular multiple component share data by service not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

This is share service (dShareService) =>

```
@Injectable()
export class DInfoShareService {
    constructor() { }

    // Observable sources    
    private dInfo = new Subject<DInfo>();

    dInfo$ = this.dInfo.asObservable();

    // Service message commands
  public SetDInfo(dinfo: DInfo) {     
    this.dInfo.next(dinfo);
  }
}
```

This is parent =>

At the parent, I have the button click event and pass data to the method and value is the pass to service.

```
GoToDetail(value){       
    this.dShareService.SetDInfo(value);

    //this is child component and call by route, basically, I use this state and pass data to child 
    //component but this time, I have 3 tab page at UI and each page needs this data.
   
 this.router.navigateByUrl('/dchild', {
          state: {dInfo: value}
    });
```

This is the child component =>

At the constructor ,

```
this.dinfoShareService.dInfo$.subscribe(res=>
     {
       //this one never happen
       this.dInfo = res;
     } 
  );
```

This subscribes at the child is never trigger. May I know what I am wrong?

Comment: use a BehaviorSubject instead

Comment: @enno.void Thanks. I changed to BehaviourSubject and work like expected.

Answer (score 3):

Try Like this,
Service.ts  file

```
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiWalletService {
  private behave = new BehaviorSubject<Object>('');

  setBehaviorView(behave: object) {
    this.behave.next(behave);
  }

  /** Get Behavior for user registraion */
  getBehaviorView(): Observable<object> {
    return this.behave.asObservable();
  }

}
```

component1.ts

```
 {
     ngOnInit() {
            this.setBehaviorView({
              'data':'XYZ'
            })
       }
    }
```

component2.ts

```
{

 constructor(private service: Service){}

 ngOnInit() {
 this.service.getBehaviorView().subscribe(async (data) => {
   if (data && data != undefined) {
      console.log(data)
    }
  })
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong implemntation for the Subject inisde your service :

```
@Injectable()
export class DInfoShareService {
    constructor() { }

    // Observable sources    
    private dInfo = new Subject<DInfo>();


    // Service message commands
  public SetDInfo(dinfo: DInfo) {     
    this.dInfo.next(dinfo);
  }
}
```

It not should be called inside the constructor, use it inside ngOninit

```
     ngOnInit(): void {

this.dinfoShareService.dInfo.subscribe(res=>
     {
       //this one never happen
       this.dInfo = res;
     } 
  );


});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your decorator into this `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` to make it singleton across components. Else it will provide multiple instances for multiple components.

Also noticed that :

```
GoToDetail(value){       
    this.dShareService.SetDInfo(value);   
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/dchild', {
          state: {dInfo: value}
    });
}
```

The above code calls the `SetDInfo` method before the navigation. So your child component subscribes after the value set. You need to change your `Subject` to `BehaviorSubject` so that you can read the last set value.